# Node-LinkedIn module returns "Unknown Authentication Scheme"

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication

I'm using the node-linkedin npm package to authenticate and read information about from other users (name, job title, company name, profile pic, shared connections). I can correctly receive and store the access token (verified in my own LinkedIn profile's approved apps & console logging the token), but I am unable to return any of the requested information. My calls are copied & pasted from the package docs, but it returns the following:

```
2018-02-28T03:46:53.459839+00:00 app[web.1]: { errorCode: 0,
2018-02-28T03:46:53.459843+00:00 app[web.1]:   message: 'Unknown authentication scheme',
2018-02-28T03:46:53.459845+00:00 app[web.1]:   requestId: '3B55EVY7XQ',
2018-02-28T03:46:53.459847+00:00 app[web.1]:   status: 401,
2018-02-28T03:46:53.459848+00:00 app[web.1]:   timestamp: 1519789613443 }
```

I have included my routes below. Solely for the purpose of testing, myToken and linkedin are server-side global variables to the linkedin-controller scope. (I understand this will need to change for the final product, which is a student project.)

```
app.get('/companies', function (req, res) {
    console.log(linkedin.connections.config.accessToken);
    linkedin.companies_search.name('facebook', 1, function(err, company) {
        console.log('Merpy merpy mc merpers'
            ,company);
        // name = company.companies.values[0].name;
        // desc = company.companies.values[0].description;
        // industry = company.companies.values[0].industries.values[0].name;
        // city = company.companies.values[0].locations.values[0].address.city;
        // websiteUrl = company.companies.values[0].websiteUrl;
        res.redirect("/");
    });
});

app.get('/companies2', function (req, res) {
    linkedin.companies.company('162479', function(err, company) {
        console.log(company);
        res.redirect("/");
    });
});

app.get('/connections', function (req, res) {
    linkedin.connections.retrieve(function(err, connections) {
        console.log(connections);
        res.redirect("/");
    });
});
```

This is my authorization code, which appears to work:

```
    app.get('/auth', function (req, res) {
    // This is the redirect URI which linkedin will call to and provide state and code to verify
    /**
     *
     * Attached to the redirect_uri will be two important URL arguments that you need to read from the request:

     code — The OAuth 2.0 authorization code.
     state — A value used to test for possible CSRF attacks.
     */

    //TODO: validate state here to secure against CSRF
    var error = req.query.error;
    var error_description = req.query.error_description;
    var state = req.query.state;
    var code = req.query.code;
    if (error) {
        next(new Error(error));
    }
    /**
     *
     * The code is a value that you will exchange with LinkedIn for an actual OAuth 2.0 access
     * token in the next step of the authentcation process.  For security reasons, the authorization code
     * has a very short lifespan and must be used within moments of receiving it - before it expires and
     * you need to repeat all of the previous steps to request another.
     */
    //once the code is received handshake back with linkedin to send over the secret key
    handshake(req.query.code, res);
});

function handshake(code, ores) {

    //set all required post parameters
    var data = querystring.stringify({
        grant_type: "authorization_code",
        code: code,
        redirect_uri: OauthParams.redirect_uri,//should match as in Linkedin application setup
        client_id: OauthParams.client_id,
        client_secret: OauthParams.client_secret// the secret
    });

    var options = {
        host: 'www.linkedin.com',
        path: '/oauth/v2/accessToken',
        protocol: 'https:',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data)
        }
    };

    var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
        var data = '';
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            data += chunk;

        });
        res.on('end', function () {
            //once the access token is received store it
            myToken = JSON.parse(data);
            linkedin = Linkedin.init(myToken);
            ores.redirect("/");
        });
        req.on('error', function (e) {
            console.log("problem with request: " + e.message);
        });

    });
    req.write(data);
    req.end();
}
```

In my troubleshooting research, it seems I need to pass the token into the request; however, I can't find anywhere or any way to do so in the package. And with as many daily downloads as the package has, I can't possibly be the only one to experience this error. The author's Issues section of GitHub were unhelpful, as were other searches for this package's error.

**My deployment:** https://linkedin-api-test.herokuapp.com/

- (When visiting the deployment, you must click the blue "Want to
  connect to LinkedIn?" link prior to manually changing the uri
  according to the routes. The results will also only display in the
  Heroku logs, which is most likely largely unhelpful to you. It was
  supposed to be a simple test, so I simply stole the front end from my
  prior project.)

**My Repo:** https://github.com/SteveSonoa/LinkedIn-Test

**node-linkedin Docs:** https://github.com/ArkeologeN/node-linkedin/blob/master/README.md

This is my first question I haven't been able to find the answer to; I apologize if I left out anything important while asking. Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to pass the following token code into the linkedin variable instead of simply passing myToken:

```
linkedin = Linkedin.init(myToken.access_token || myToken.accessToken);
```

I don't understand the downvote, as no comments were left; I apologize if I left out important or generally expected information, as this was the first question I've asked. I want to make sure the solution is posted for anyone coming after me with the same issue. This issue is now solved.